# XAMPP Mysql Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25), unpredictable error

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, xampp, mariadb

I have been trying to figure out this error for a while now with XAMPP and MySQL. When I try to execute my code I get the following :

Static analysis:
1 errors were found during analysis.
Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Copy Edit Edit
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
MySQL said: Documentation
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Explanation of error:
I have searched online for this error, but none of them have worked, I have checked my query statements they seem to be fine.
Like I mentioned when I run my code it gives the error, however, I've noticed if I take away, for example, the code that I use to create a new user and grant roles, and then execute the code it works fine with 0 errors. But then if I re-add another select statement e.g `select * from the customer;` or anything it gives me the exact same error. So I have no idea what is causing the issue.

I am using XAMPP version 7.3.26, and the PHPMyAdmin + mysql editor, executing the code in the "SQL" tab.

CODE TO REPRODUCE THE ERROR

```
https://pastebin.com/VGvjPZVU
```

Sorry, it's Pastebin, as StackOverflow is saying it spam? however, the entire code is needed to reproduce the error. (especially since the error is very vague could be anything)

Comment: @RiggsFolly that the issue i am finding it impossible to pin point what specfic code is the issue, its just when i run that code as a whole, if i remove a seelct query for example it then works, but if I add some random new select query after then run it magically gives me that error once again.

Comment: Ok, so as its XAMPP I assume it is actually mariaDB you aer using, unless you have a very old version of XAMPP

Comment: So which version of mariaDB are you using

Comment: @RiggsFolly show this 10.4.22-MariaDB when i run this command select @@version as version;

Comment: I've seen ON/OFF specified as values too, but try with 0/1 values instead to see if it makes any difference. The documentation has: `If set to 1 (the default) foreign key constraints (including ON UPDATE and ON DELETE behavior) InnoDB tables are checked, while if set to 0, they are not checked.`

Comment: @PaulT. Hi paul, can you just clarify what you are suggesting I try, little confused on what you mean. Thank you. :)

Comment: ? `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` for `ON` ... `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` for `OFF`.

Comment: @PaulT. oh i see what you mean, xampp has a button that does that and I still get the same error with it on and off.

Comment: I don't know then, I cannot reproduce. Try [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3ff71a0afce1b3c054e438700660e6ad) ... I had to comment out the DB create and use statements, but no errors. See lines 10 and 352 with the `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` added.

Comment: I see what you mean, however even without the foreign key checks, it seems to work, or am I missing something.